# Rewrite union query to a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wondered if it was possible to write this as one query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT  "markets".* 
  FROM "markets" 
  INNER JOIN "positions" ON "positions"."id" = "markets"."position_id" 
  INNER JOIN "players" ON "players"."id" = "positions"."player_id" 
  INNER JOIN "other_players" ON "other_players"."id" = "players"."other_player_id" 
  WHERE (markets.updated_at > '2021-01-10 11:50:14.136015') 
  AND "markets"."on_feed" = true
  AND "markets"."deleted_at" IS NULL

  UNION

  SELECT  "markets".* 
  FROM "markets" 
  WHERE (markets.updated_at > '2021-01-10 11:50:14.136015') 
  AND "markets"."on_feed" = true 
  AND "markets"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL) results
ORDER BY results.updated_at DESC
```

There's a lot of overlap in the two queries. In the first one we want all markets that have those associations in place. For the 2nd query we don't really care if the associations are there or not.

Comment: Try changing those all to left joins. You might need to move the not null condition into the join clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT * FROM "markets" 
  LEFT JOIN "positions" ON "positions"."id" = "markets"."position_id" 
  LEFT JOIN "players" ON "players"."id" = "positions"."player_id" 
  LEFT JOIN "other_players" ON "other_players"."id" = "players"."other_player_id" 
  WHERE markets.updated_at > '2021-01-10 11:50:14.136015'
  AND "markets"."on_feed" = true
  AND ("markets"."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL 
  OR "positions"."id" IS NOT NULL AND "players"."id" IS NOT NULL 
      AND "other_players"."id" IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER BY markets.updated_at DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` instead:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM "markets"  m
WHERE m.updated_at > '2021-01-10 11:50:14.136015' AND
      markets."on_feed" = true AND
      (m."deleted_at" IS NOT NULL OR
       EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM "positions" p JOIN 
                    "players" pl
                    ON pl."id" = p."player_id" JOIN
                    "other_players" op
                    ON op."id" = p."other_player_id" 
               WHERE p."id" = m."position_id" 
              )
      )
ORDER BY m.updated_at DESC
```